# Remove special characters in contact us

Tags: joomla-2.5

I want the joomla contact us page to stop accepting special characters in the form fields.

like

Name : must accept only alphabets either Uppercase or lowercase and absolutely nothing else.

similarly

subject :  must accept only alphabets either Uppercase or lowercase and absolutely nothing else.

i tried using filters in the global configuration.doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Check out jquery validate.

Comment: is it a plugin available ?